# Will SQL 2008 SSIS package files work with SQL 2016 databases after database upgrades?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, upgrade

We plan to upgrade SQL 2008R2 to SQL 2016. We want to upgrade database servers first. We have separate SQL 2008R2 servers for SSIS and SSRS. SSIS packages are stored as files.

My question is:

After upgrading all database servers to SQL 2016, will all the SQL 2008R2 SSIS and SSRS servers work with the SQL 2016 databases?

Appreciate your experience.

Answer (score 6):

At our location, we have SSIS running on SQL Server 2012. Our databases are on SQL Server 2016. We haven't had any issues with any of them, but then again, it really depends on what your packages are doing.

My recommendation is to have some sort of "sandbox" server and restore one of the databases and change the compatibility level to the latest level. Then test the SSIS packages to see if they would work.

Comment: Thanks!  This certainly will encourage our dev teams to upgrade their databases to SQL 2016.